# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline, Read Environment Variables from C# Code

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I thought the variables set in the Variables tab in a release pipeline were set as environment variables? 
On my TestCase Project I've got some settings stored as environment variables which are accessed during setup process of my tests, but in azure release pipeline it just comes back as null(this is using a hosted agent).

How can I access the Variables set in Variables tab of a release pipeline from my C# code?

My code to access Environment variables at the moment is

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevOpsUserName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
```

This doesn't pull back the variables data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *are* set as environment variables (excepting secret variables, which are not automatically converted to environment variables for security reasons).

However, they're not **machine**-level environment variables. They are **process**-level.

Use `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevOpsUserName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)`, as Daniel mentioned.

Or you can directly use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevOpsUserName")`, which is equivalent to the previous statement and targets the **process**-level environment variables.